# Raspberry Pi Pico reinicia los archivos cuando la desconecto

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, micropython

Ayer conseguí una Raspberry Pi Pico y el problema que tengo es que cuando la desconecto del cable USB se reinicia y borra todos los archivos que le meto. Lo he intentado varias veces pero no funciona. Además cuando le introduzco el archivo .uf2 se desconecta repentinamente y cuando la vuelvo a conectar se borran todos los archivos. ¿Alguien puede decirme por qué ocurre y cuál sería una posible solución?

Comment: Como estas guardando los archivos? Es muy grande?

Comment: El archivo que guardé es el .uf2 que se descarga en la página oficial de Raspberry para incluir micropython. Los guardo desde el explorador de archivos de Windows 10 y el editor de código de Thonny.

Comment: Utiliza Thinny para instalar Micropython, es la manera más sencilla utilizando el Pi Pico